# how to convert the new input non-numerical-data into numerical data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

**OUTLINE:**
I want to know **how to keep the new input non-numerical-data as the unique one!**

**DESCRIBE:**
Namely, when we finish both train and test period, lot of new data that **unions numerical and non-numerical data** input into my model.

**ISSUE(1):**
 Thus, the first important matter is **convert these new mixed data into a dataframe with all numerical format!!**

**TRIED METHOD:**

How can we do that? I used LabelEncoder to transform every non-numerical data into float type, however, the member of SCIKIT-LEARN feedbacked me that LabelEncoder is only available for Label[Y] and I should use OneHotEncoder
convert feature. 
[He answered me at URL: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8674], while misunderstanding my meaning

Unfortunately, OneHotEncoder is only available for integer feature by SCIKIT-LEARN Official documentation said in p.1829.

I know there is a title about 'Feature Union with Heterogeneous Data Sources', while it is not convenient as LabelEncoder does.
**ISSUE(2):**
The second reason why such issue confuses me is related to how we can ensure the input new non-numerical data can be transform into an unique value that differs from the previous-transformed-training-data or previous-transformed-test-data. Namely, although we can use LabelEncoder transform new input data into numerical data, there is a risk that the transformed data[in the new input data yield] might be equal to the transformed data[in the previous transformed data]

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Two Issues: (1) how can we transform mixed data(string and numerical) into numerical data; (2)how can we ensure the new input mixed data(string and numerical) can be transformed into numerical data as the unique one,which differs from previous transformed data(train data and test data)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have been answered by the official guys. The follow URL maybe helpful for somebody who confused about this issue.

https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/blob/master/04-representing-data-feature-engineering.ipynb